# Block Validation Process, in Terms of adding Block to the Chain

Tags: block, validation

quick question - How does a Node react to a new block propagated to the network?
In Terms to  does a Miner stop mining when "he" gets information of a new block to validate it? or does it not stop and validate it in another Thread?

If the Question is unclear - let me know I just began my deep dive into the technical side of Crypto and Blockchain :)

best regards :)

Answer (score 1):

It is easy and instant to confirm that a hashes proposed by a miner is the correct one, so once it is received by a node, miner, he will immediately stop trying to find a correct hashes for the previous block and began searching the new one without transition.

Comment: Hey, 
thanks for the answer - just to recap it for my understanding - 

As soon i (presumably I'm mining on a Block atm) get a new block propagated i just stop working on mine, quickly validate the block i got propagated and start with a new block?

Comment: yes, notice that in any case you will need the hashes (number) to start working (hashing) on the next block